# Getting Postgres Exception : cannot commit while a subtransaction is active

Tags: postgresql, exception, transactions, postgresql-9.3

We have the update query inside the transaction block with the exception block. Shown below:

```
do $$       
begin

    update dbo.myTable set name = 'Table Name' where id = 47;
    commit;

exception when others then 

       raise notice '% %', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE;
    rollback;

end; $$ 
language 'plpgsql';
```

But this will return an exception raised message which *is cannot commit while a subtransaction is active 2D000*. Any leads on this issue and how can we support this transaction behaviour?

Comment: You can't have transaction control inside a PL/pgSQL block. Also: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Any clue, on how we can handle this query syntax? any way out?

Comment: You don't need a PL/pgSQL block anyway. Just run the update, if an error occurs you will be forced to rollback anyway.

Comment: You're trying to implement default behavior in using pretty complex code, code that is not supported this way. Drop all your code and just keep the UPDATE, and it works. Check the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html

Comment: there are multiple update queries in this begin block... for the sake of simplicity I have mentioned only one update query. So it may happen that one update succeeds and the second would get failed.

Comment: The fact that you have multiple updates doesn't change anything. Just run them all in a single transaction: `begin transaction; update ...; update ...;  commit;` - if one of them fails, you can't commit the transaction.

Comment: yes, you are right.. things looking good.